# Can you run P2Pool without having to keep the blockchain updated?

Tags: blockchain, p2pool

I'm guessing the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I'm running my miner off a USB pen at the moment and I'd like to run P2Pool but the main issue for me is there wouldn't be enough space left on the USB pen to store the blockchain.

Is there a way I can run P2Pool without having the blockchain stored locally?

Comment: The blockchain will probably be under 2GB for at least the next year. Isn't a bigger usb drive a trivial cost compared to your hardware and electricity?

Comment: I'd prefer a longer term solution

Comment: then you can buy a 16gb stick, for about 15-20usd, and that would last you for quite a while. :) but yes, as the answers suggest, you can run a bitcoind anywhere and connect to it remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run the Bitcoin client on a separate machine, and connect to it over the network.

Answer (score 1):

When you run p2pool, you can provide extra flags to tell it where to find the bitcoind to connect to:

```
bitcoind interface:
  --bitcoind-address BITCOIND_ADDRESS   : connect to this address (default: 127.0.0.1)
  --bitcoind-rpc-port BITCOIND_RPC_PORT : connect to JSON-RPC interface at this port (default: 8332)
  --bitcoind-p2p-port BITCOIND_P2P_PORT : connect to P2P interface at this port (default: 8333)
  BITCOIND_RPCUSERPASS                  : bitcoind RPC interface username, then password, space-separated
```